# 'Not' followed by 'as was the case of' is possible?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I'm wondering if the phrase

> Not as was the case of [...]

is possible.

For making it clear, the synonym is *"Not like the case of ..."*.

Comment: What do you think of *"Not as was the case of Louis XVI, who has been beheaded."*

Comment: I can understand the meaning, but as for me it looks awkward.

Comment: If I heard someone say this, it would sound like they were starting to phrase it differently, and changed direction after having said _not as_.

Comment: @YohannV. The case died young? I think you had something like "as it was the case **with**" in mind.

Comment: @YohannV. "The case of a man dying old" would be fine. "The case of the missing statue was hard to solve. As was the case of the man in the river. Or the opposite: Unlike the case of the man in the river." I've never stumbled upon an idiom with "the case of" other than "in the case of". And I have yet to find a situation where "not as was" would be correct.

Comment: @zeroflagL I moved my comments to an anwer

Comment: At the very least I'd change the word order to "As was not the case of [...]".  But probably best to avoid the form entirely -- at it's best it's borderline awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase is lacking a little in context but, assuming you are using the phrase to introduce a contrasting example, it's most likely that you mean to say *unlike the case of*. It's quite likely that in context even this is a little unwieldy and you can get away with a simple *unlike*.

For example

> John was hot, unlike Mary, who had no coat.

If you are using this construction to switch the topic to that of the contrasting example, it is better to use "unlike" first in an initial parenthetical statement.

> Unlike lemons, car batteries have negligible internal resistance and so can easily deliver hundreds of amps into the starter motor of a Winnebago.

or

> Unlike Dr Crippen, Tarquin had hired an excellent barrister.

or

> Unlike those earlier crimes, the thief had been careless.

or

> Unlike her governess earlier in the week, Lucinda thought it appropriate to loosen her corset after dinner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, so this answer is only speculations. It will raise interest on this post and avoid the discuss in comments.

Moreover, I don't know what OP wants so, I am trying to explain by what I understand.

---

> Is *"Not as was the case of [...]"* possible?

I am using this example to figure out :

> Louix XIV died of old age at 76. **Not as was the case of** Louis XVI, who has been beheaded at 38.

I think the *"in"* and the *"it"* here are implied :

> Not as [*it*] was [*in*] the case of Louis XVI, who has been beheaded.

I wouldn't use this and I think it is weird, but it may be right